# Property with 2 compatible classes

Tags: c#

Permission

```
public enum PermissionType
{
    Read = 0,
    Write = 1
}

public class Permission
{
    public virtual PermissionType? Type { get; set; }
}

public class PermissionCreate : Permission
{
    [Required]
    [Range(0, 1)]
    public override PermissionType? Type { get; set; }
}
```

Category

```
public class Category
{
    public virtual int? Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Permission Permission { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryCreate : Category
{
    [Required]
    public override string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public override PermissionCreate Permission { get; set; }
}
```

The line `public override PermissionCreate Permission { get; set; }` throws a error because it needs to match the overridden member type. Is there a way to override the property with both Permission and PermissionCreate since they are compatible?

Comment: Can you explain more? You're question is unclear to me.

Comment: pls, see update. hope it is better.

Comment: You can't change the signature of a member when you override it. You can, however, assign an object of type `PermissionCreate` to the base `Permission` property, since `PermissionCreate` descends from `Permission`. You simply won't (easily) know that it is of `PermissionCreate` type since the property type will be `Permission`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `PermissionCreate` class already derives from `Permission`:

```
public class PermissionCreate : Permission
```

then you can already assign a `PermissionCreate` object to your `Permission` property.

But yes, the derived class must match the parent class exactly. So if you do this:

```
public class CategoryCreate : Category
{
    [Required]
    public override string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public override Permission Permission { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
var test = new CategoryCreate { Permission = new PermissionCreate() };
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a `CategoryCreate` class. Instead create an `Category` instance with a `PermissionCreate` object:

```
Category Create = new Category();
Create.Permission = new PermissionCreate();
```